# NGINX - Why i am getting "Permission denied" error code 13?

Tags: nginx

i finished setup of my first nginx server and i noticed the following error on `nginx t` command.

Error mesage:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2020/12/12 19:25:26 [warn] 1498#1498: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2020/12/12 19:25:26 [emerg] 1498#1498: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

My NGINX config file as is now:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        # For Basic Auth
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        # Basic Settings
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        # SSL Settings
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # Logging Settings
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        # Gzip Settings
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_min_length 1100;

        # Virtual Host Configs
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        # Harden nginx against DDOS
        client_header_timeout 10;
        client_body_timeout   10;
        keepalive_timeout     10 10;
        send_timeout          10;
```

}

How can i fix this error? Is my config file fine? I am using a raspberry pi as a home server for my projects. I am using SSH to communicate with my server and i am able to read with `sudo nano` the error log file.

Answer (score 1):

MUST use `sudo` and not simple `nginx t`...

The correct command:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

And the output:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```